# Noestests: AttributeError using @patch when running Nosetests on multiple files

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, nose

I am running nosetests across multiple files and getting an error relating to the importing of a specific file, well I'm not actually sure what the error is related to, I think it is either something up with the import or something up with the patching of it. The error itself looks like:

(I'm getting one of these errors for each test function that uses an @patch decorator)

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/venvs/migration/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/case.py", line 67, in testPartExecutor
yield
  File "/home/user/Documents/venvs/migration/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/case.py", line 625, in run
testMethod()
  File "/home/user/Documents/venvs/migration/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1297, in patched
arg = patching.__enter__()
  File "/home/user/Documents/venvs/migration/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1353, in __enter__
self.target = self.getter()
  File "/home/user/Documents/venvs/migration/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1523, in <lambda>
getter = lambda: _importer(target)
  File "/home/user/Documents/venvs/migration/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1210, in _importer
thing = _dot_lookup(thing, comp, import_path)
  File "/home/user/Documents/venvs/migration/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1200, in _dot_lookup
return getattr(thing, comp)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'utils'
```

The package structure looks like this:

```
my_package
    - my_module
        - __init__.py
        - utils.py
        - other.py
    - tests
        - test_utils.py
        - test_other.py
```

The nosetests command:

`nosetests -e unit --with-coverage --cover-package=my_package --cover-erase --cover-xml --with-xunit tests --nocapture`

So the weird thing is, if I run nosetests only on the utils test class itself, it runs fine, all imports work and all patches work, no errors, all tests pass.

Here's what the test_utils.py file looks like:

```
from my_module.utils import *

class TestBusinessProcess(unittest2.TestCase):        

    @patch('my_module.utils.something')
    def test_some_utils_function(self, something_mock):
        # test implementation..
        # this function will throw:
        # AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'utils'
        # when running whole tests folder and not on individual test file
        pass

    @patch('my_module.utils.something_else')
    def test_some_other_utils_function(self, something_else_mock):
        # test implementation..
        # same as above
        pass
```

An example of a test in the other test file that has no issues when ran either way:

```
from my_module.other import *

class TestBusinessProcess(unittest2.TestCase):        

    @patch('my_module.other.something')
    def test_some_function(self, something_mock):
        # test implementation..
        # no issues!
        pass

    @patch('my_module.other.something_else')
    def test_some_other_function(self, something_else_mock):
        # test implementation..
        # no issues!
        pass
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea what was wrong, but it seemed to be something to do with the importing.

Anyway, this workaround solved the problem, but not sure why exactly.

The `__init__.py` in `my_module` was empty initially. Then I edited it to expose the individual functions of `utils.py`:

`__init__.py`

```
from utils import test_some_utils_function, test_some_other_utils_function

__all__ = [
    "test_some_utils_function",
    "test_some_other_utils_function"
]
```